# Use a model to reduce sample size?

Tags: sample-size, model, sample

I have a consultant that is proposing that he can reduce my sample size by using a model that is built off of previous samples.  My first response was "NEVER EVER EVER EVER DO THIS".  However, after hearing more, I believe this might work.

I am trying to estimate the energy output of a building in county 1.  I already have samples (let's say 100 samples is statistically significant) of buildings in county 2.  The obvious answer is that you can never ever apply the results of your samples in county 2 to county 1.  But why?  Because the weather is different, they are different building types, with different businesses in them, with different operating hours, etc.

BUT, what if I created a factor model that controlled for these variables?  For instance, a restaurant in county 2 with the same operating hours as a restaurant in county 1, same size, same weather, should have the same energy usage, also.

1. Armed with this model, can I reduce my sample size in county 1?
2. By how much?
3. I assume I would combine the output of the model (using known input data from county 1) with samples from county 1.  How would I do that?  Average them together?
4. How do I then calculate my CI?

Comment: Why do you want to reduce your sample size? For me the only reason would be if it's computationally infeasible to perform calculations with your full dataset.

Comment: If county 2 -based model includes weather, building type, etc, as factors, then you can use it directly for county 1 by plugging in the county-1-specific values of all the factors. In that case, you don't need to sample in county 1 at all. Incidentally, that will serve as a reality check for the model.

Comment: Bar - I need to reduce sample size to reduce cost.
James - A test case showed that using only the model does not get me to the 10% CI that I need.  This would necessitate the need to collect more samples from county 1.